PHP Issue checking if number has two decimal
I ran into a curious issue when I was trying to validate if the number has two decimal places in PHP.
I created the following function:
<?php
function hasTwoDecimal(float $number): bool
{
    return intval($number*100) == $number*100;
}

This function works pretty well, except when the number is 2055.49, returning false.
I added to the function a debug:
function hasTwoDecimal(float $number): bool
{
    echo $number . "\n";
    echo intval($number*100) . "\n";
    echo $number * 100 . "\n";
    return intval($number*100) == $number * 100;
}

And for my surprise hasTwoDecimal(2055.49) returns:
2055.49
205548
205549

My PHP version is:
❯ php -v
PHP 8.3.12 (cli) (built: Sep 27 2024 03:53:29) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.3.12, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.3.12, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v3.3.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2024, by Derick Rethans

This seems to be a bizarre bug in PHP, so it will be really difficult to have it fixed fast. How would be a better way to check if the number has two decimal?

Change intval() to round().

2055.49 can't be represented exactly, it's actually 2055.48999999999978172127. When you multiply by 100 you get 205548.999999999978172127, and it gets rounded down by intval()

Excellent explanation. Round works to output the number. However, the validation, (round($dto->getAmount()*100) != ($dto->getAmount()*100)) still returning false.

Numbers don't have a number of decimal places. They only get decimal places when they're formatted. Internally they're stored in binary, not decimal.

var_dump(2055.49 == 2055.48999999999978172127); produces true -- there's no way to tell which was actually assigned to $number.

If you care about this, you should use a string variable rather than float. Then you can use a simple regexp.

It is because I got this number from some calculations in the code. I just need to guarantee I am not receiving a number with 3 or more decimals, like 10.305 before saving it to the database.
Thanks to your explanation, I narrowed down to: round($number*100)/100 != $number.
It passed in the tests, but I am not sure if it will pass for all numbers based on the rounding to store the number.

That's not possible, since the numbers are not represented in decimal internally.

The best you can do is check whether it's close to an integer value when you multiply by 100.

I did echo "$number: " . (round($number*100)/100 == $number ? "ok" : "false") . "\n"; for the following list: 1055, 1055.4, 1055.45, 1055.49, 1055.499, 2055, 2055.4, 2055.45, 2055.49, 2055.499 and I got the expected result. The result I expected is to get false for 2055.499 and 1055.499.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Why do you need to validate the "number of decimal places"? What meaning is there in this? All number have infinite numbers of decimal places. What you likely need to do is implement a rounding or string formatting procedure that gives you the result you expect. Or otherwise changing the internal representation of the values you're storing to ensure fixed precision.
